# WMA decoding with ffmpeg failed

Tags: android, ffmpeg, codec

I have problem in decoding WMA/WMAPRO stream with ffmpeg.i have filled extra data from the coming stream.I am able to get bit rate, sample rate, extradata size and other parameters so there is no problem with the codecCtx initilization.

```
avcodec_open(codecCtx, codec);
```

returns -1

Anyone help me!